# How to make a rectangle change color faster over time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application where a rectangle changes color between red and black in one second over a 10 second period. What I want is to be able to change colors quicker as the elapse milliseconds reaches 6 second (6000 ms).

I have it working (mostly) but the issue is that it toggles WAY too fast after the 2 second mark. I would hope that it would get faster as it approaches the final seconds.

Here is the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Timers;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SoftBlink(6000); //6 seconds...
        }

        private async void SoftBlink(short CycleTime_ms)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();

            int interval = 500;

            while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < CycleTime_ms)
            {
                await Task.Delay(interval);
                recTest.Fill = Brushes.Red;
                await Task.Delay(interval);
                recTest.Fill = Brushes.Black;

                interval -= (int)(interval * 0.5);
            }
            sw.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you're halfing your interval each time. Try slowing the interval decrease. For example **interval -= (int)(interval * 0.2);**

Comment: As a side remark: consider using a color animation

Comment: @Paul it certainly gives the right effect but if I want to change the time to, oh say, 10 seconds the flickering looks different. I want the same fast-flicking effect happening at the end of any countdown. Thanks

Comment: You can make the interval decrease proportional to the **CycleTime_ms**. Try this: **interval -= (int)Math.Round(interval * ((CycleTime_ms / 1000) * 0.0333f));**

Comment: What you could do is to set the flash-timer-frequency for each second. So when the timer hits 6 seconds, flash twice as fast. When the timer hits 8 seconds, make it flash twice as fast as on 6 seconds. etc etc. And do that for all the different speeds you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of animation needs to be done with a storyboard; manipulating color with task await won't really give expected results.

This is quite straight foward with Storyboard animation. You will need to use ColorAnimation with [PowerEase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.powerease?view=netframework-4.7) function which will allow you gradually increase or decrease animation speed/transition.

Here is a simple example, clicking the button will change the rectangle's fill color. It will run the storyboard for 6 seconds. Animation is 0.5 seconds long, but storyboard will be repeated over and over in code until we reach 6 seconds. At each iteration, we will increase the Power property to speed up the color transition.

Manipulate the powerFactor value to see what works well. You can also play with [EasingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.easingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Xaml**

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Flash">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Black">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingColorKeyFrame>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Flash" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red">
        </Rectangle>

        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="246,0,196,34.04" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    private static readonly double powerFactor = .3;
    private Storyboard storyboard;
    private PowerEase easingFunction;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //handle the completed event to re-execute the storyboard
        this.storyboard = this.Resources["Storyboard1"] as Storyboard;
        this.storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;

        //get the animation to locate our easing function defined in xaml.
        var animation = storyboard.Children[0] as ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames;

        //find the second keyframe, thats the one that has easing function.
        this.easingFunction = (animation.KeyFrames[1] as EasingColorKeyFrame).EasingFunction as PowerEase;


    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer.Reset();
        this.timer.Start();
        this.easingFunction.Power = 0;

        RunStoryboard();
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 6000)
        {
            RunStoryboard();
        }
    }

    private void RunStoryboard()
    {
        this.easingFunction.Power += powerFactor;
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: ty, ty, ty!!! I'm very new to WPF so the Storyboard class took me by surprise. I will do further research.